# Why won't react import and use my css styles?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I built a website in adobe XD and then exported to html and now I am trying to get the react component to accept css styling! I've tried using css-loader, here's my config,

```
module: {
  rules: [
      // use ts-loader for ts and js files so all files are converted to es5
      { test: /\.(tsx?|js)$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'ts-loader' },
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'source-map-loader' },
      { test: /\.css$/, use: ['css-loader']},
  ],
},
```

I import my css by using `import "./styles.css"`

which is in the src folder, and I've styled through devtools and not issue there. I don't get any errors in the console just the fact that the css doesn't ever actually work! I've battled this one for a while now so if you see something I am doing wrong let me know! I just started react but I've done web design before and a unstyled plain html page looks terrible!

here:
[image: Structure of my file system]

Comment: Your css is in the `src` folder? Is your React component also in the `src` folder?

Comment: Yes I edited the post above with a image to show the structure

Comment: You can import like this `import style from './style.css'`, and then use it like this in the component: `<div className={style.something}>Something</div>`.

Comment: Nada! that does not work! Do I somehow need to separate the css from the JavaScript? Devtools doesn't show a css file sent at all.

Comment: Did you follow the [instructions on how to set up a React app](https://adobexdplatform.com/plugin-docs/tutorials/quick-start-react/)? You maybe missing `style-loader`.

Comment: Wait are you saying that I write css for a class and then I set the classname of the tag to that class? When I verbatim copy what you put but with my file, it doesn't work! It should work with .intro{style:style}

Comment: @Andy Ok progress! When I put {style.intro} into the class name it says it can't understand that! I may habe not installed style-loader oops! :(

Comment: YES! I got it working thanks for the help!

Comment: I tend to have one CSS file per component, and then import and use it like how I mentioned. It makes for much cleaner and easily maintainable CSS because you're not creating a massive CSS file for all of the components. Glad I could help in some way :) @3GamersStudios